# Facing issue KeyError while formatting string which contains JSON

Tags: python, string, elasticsearch, f-string

In below code I'm facing KeyError, even though my syntax seems fine.

```
data = {'id': 20720}
query = '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"status.keyword":"Running"}},{"term":{"id":{id}}}],"filter":[{"term":{"status.keyword":"Running"}}]}}}'
print(query.format(**data))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\demo.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(query.format(**data))
KeyError: '"query"'
```

Here I'm formatting Elasticsearch query, I don't wanted to use replace string because I have to iterate it multiple time if **data** contains more field.

I'm expecting below output.

`{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"status.keyword":"Running"}},{"term":{"id":20720}}],"filter":[{"term":{"status.keyword":"Running"}}]}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double your curly braces except the ones around the `id` variable

```
query = '{{"query":{{"bool":{{"must"... {{"term":{{"id":{id} }} }}...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use single `{}` around some text and try to use `format` method, it expects all the attributes that are enclosed in `{}`. So if you look at the query string, the first `{` found is around query are we are only passing `id` to the format method. It's expecting query as well so that's why you are getting this error.

To resolve the issue, you need to wrap all key values in `{{}}` to escape the format method keyword arguments. You need to wrap only those values that you want to replace later on with single `{}` but all others should be wrapped around `{{}}`. Following is the fixed code.

```
data = {'id': 20720}
query = '{{"query":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"status.keyword":"Running"}}}},{{"term":{{"id":{id}}}}}],"filter": [{{"term":{{"status.keyword":"Running"}}}}]}}}}}}'
print(query.format(**data))
```

You will see following output:
`{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"status.keyword":"Running"}},{"term":{"id":20720}}],"filter": [{"term":{"status.keyword":"Running"}}]}}}`

Comment: Thanks @Itezaz for your explaination, It helped a lot.